# Building the computation graph form an expression

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement different differentiation algorithms.

I'm having trouble breaking up an expression like this:

```
x = Variable()
y = Variable()
F_x = (x**2) * y + y + 2
```

I want to build the graph for F_x.

Edit: To clarify the graph of F_x would look something like

> ```
>        Add
>       / \
>     Mult  Add 
>     /  \  / \
>   EXP  y  y  2 
>   /  \
>  x   2
> ```

Comment: Are you asking for a library to use for this problem?

Comment: Your question is much too vague. What do you mean by "breaking up an expression"? What is the meaning of your `Variable()` function?

Comment: @ChristMartin I know that this is provided by cgt or Theano but I'd like to learn it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python library called scipy which has functions that can produce graphs

Comment: I know that SciPy builds graphs but could I also extract the graph from any expression? I know theano already does this but this is for my own learning.